# Flutter: Image Picker method for camera works ok in debug version of app (on device), but then crashes when release version run (from Google Play)

Tags: android, flutter

I have implemented a simple image classifier from an example in an article, using Flutter. The app works as expected when the debug version is installed on an Android device. A problem occurred, however, when running the release version, downloaded from Google Play. The image picker crashes due to a null value. The Logcat for the error:

```
2022-01-14 10:50:04.501 11061-11061/? E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/image_picker: Failed to handle method call
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:220)
        at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3738)
        at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3725)
        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.f.a(Unknown Source:16)
        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.f.b(Unknown Source:15)
        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.e$a.b(Unknown Source:2)
        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.e.E(Unknown Source:6)
        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.e.J(Unknown Source:10)
        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin.a(Unknown Source:236)
        at b.a.c.a.i$a.a(Unknown Source:17)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.f.c.g(Unknown Source:18)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.f.c.h(Unknown Source:20)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.f.c.i(Unknown Source:0)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.f.a.run(Unknown Source:12)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8641)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1133)
2022-01-14 10:50:04.502 11061-20946/? E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, null, null, java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:220)
        at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3738)
        at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3725)
        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.f.a(Unknown Source:16)
        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.f.b(Unknown Source:15)
        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.e$a.b(Unknown Source:2)
        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.e.E(Unknown Source:6)
        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.e.J(Unknown Source:10)
        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin.a(Unknown Source:236)
        at b.a.c.a.i$a.a(Unknown Source:17)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.f.c.g(Unknown Source:18)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.f.c.h(Unknown Source:20)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.f.c.i(Unknown Source:0)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.f.a.run(Unknown Source:12)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8641)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1133)
    )
    #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607)
    #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      MethodChannelImagePicker.getImage (package:image_picker_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_image_picker.dart:187)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #3      _HomeState.pickImage (package:fvdemo/home.dart:58)
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

Flutter doctor:

```
PS C:\Users\chabe\Documents\Flutter projects\fvdemo\fvdemo> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1415], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at C:\Users\chabe\Documents\flutter_windows_2.8.1-stable
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (4 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\chabe\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\chabe\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\chabe\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.8)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.32002.261
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

    • VS Code at C:\Users\chabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.32.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • SM G781V (mobile) • RFCR81QTC6M • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows     • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1415]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 97.0.4692.71
    • Edge (web)        • edge        • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 97.0.1072.55
• No issues found!
```

Pubspec.yaml:

```
name: fvdemo
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"
dependencies:  
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  tflite: ^1.1.2
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  flutter:               
    assets:     
       - assets/
    uses-material-design: true
```

android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Dart code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool _loading = true;
  late File _image;
  late List _output;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadModel().then((value) {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    Tflite.close();
  }

  classifyImage(File image) async {
    var output = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
      path: image.path,
      numResults: 36,
      threshold: 0.5,
      imageMean: 127.5,
      imageStd: 127.5,
    );
    setState(() {
      _output = output!;
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  loadModel() async {
    await Tflite.loadModel(
        model: 'assets/model.tflite', labels: 'assets/labels.txt');
  }

  pickImage() async {
    var image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (image == null) return null;

    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
    });
    classifyImage(_image);
  }

  pickGalleryImage() async {
    var image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image == null) return null;

    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
    });
    classifyImage(_image);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: const Text(
          'Fruits and Veggies Neural Network',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
              fontSize: 20,
              letterSpacing: 0.8),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 35, vertical: 50),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color(0xFF2A363B),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: _loading == true
                    ? null //show nothing if no picture selected
                    : Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 250,
                            width: 250,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              child: Image.file(
                                _image,
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Divider(
                            height: 25,
                            thickness: 1,
                          ),
                          // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
                          _output != null
                              ? Text(
                                  'The object is: ${_output[0]['label']}!',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                )
                              : Container(),
                          const Divider(
                            height: 25,
                            thickness: 1,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: pickImage,
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 200,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 24, vertical: 17),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey[600],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Take A Photo',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: pickGalleryImage,
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 200,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 24, vertical: 17),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey[600],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Pick From Gallery',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Tried downgrading gradle from 4.1.0 to 3.5.4, but this caused other errors. Cannot use API below 30 according to Google Play (thought I would try e.g. 28). Added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` to the AndroidManifest (debug and profile). None of these fixed the error (the API change was not possible to test). Any solutions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginner's error. The CAMERA permission was added to the debug and profile AndroidManifests, but release uses instead: `<project name>/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xls`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).